# Rails custom position of results from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing small forum engine in Rails 5 and I'm at the part of creating new categories and forums; is it possible to implement system which will allow me to show categories / forums right before / after defined ones (like in phpBB) and how could I do that?

Example (categories#new) :

- name of category
- description of category
- position of category

I want to save that position and based on it show results from database.

Comment: By position, do you mean sort order or display order?  I.e. if position = 1, always show this category at the top of the list?

Comment: Yes, I mean that - if position is one it should be displayed on the top of list of results.

Comment: Read about the .order method in ActiveRecord  --  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering

Comment: So if I'm right, I'll just have to use parameter of position in table and pass it to order function?

Comment: Write some actual code and put it in your question and we'll be able to tell if you are on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved: as I said, simple parameter from form passed to order function will do the work.

```
@categories = Category.all.order("position ASC")
```

Where position is of course, field in the table and integer parameter written on category creation.